# Sublime Plugin RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, sublime-text-plugin

There's a class which sends

```
postdata = {"some" : "value"}
user_headesr = Config.get_headers() //returning static class variable
requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(postdata), headers=user_headers)
```

But i get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 535, in run_
    return self.run()
  File "~Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/MyPlugin/compile_code.py", line 22, in run
    compile_response = hr.send_code_to_server(code, HackerRankConfig.language)
  File "~Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/MyPlugin/plugin/hackerrank.py", line 15, in send_code_to_server
    resp = requests.post(HackerRankConfig.compile_tests_url, data=json.dumps(postdata), headers=user_headers)
  File "~Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/MyPlugin/requests/requests/api.py", line 109, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "~Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/MyPlugin/requests/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "~Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/MyPlugin/requests/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "~Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/MyPlugin/requests/requests/sessions.py", line 382, in prepare_request
    headers=merge_setting(request.headers, self.headers, dict_class=CaseInsensitiveDict),
  File "~Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/MyPlugin/requests/requests/sessions.py", line 66, in merge_setting
    for (k, v) in merged_setting.items():
  File "./collections/abc.py", line 479, in __iter__
  File "~Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/MyPlugin/requests/requests/structures.py", line 60, in <genexpr>
    return (casedkey for casedkey, mappedvalue in self._store.values())
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

- My Code is not changing the dictionary, the get_headers() reads from package.sublime-settings file.
- I've tried making the method return copy to ensure thats not causing problem, still the issue exists.
- I am using python 3.3.3, Sublime Text 3

Comment: Not the error, but the `requests` version you are using supports posting `json` directly by using `requests.post(HackerRankConfig.compile_tests_url, json=postdata, headers=user_headers)` (and you don't have to set the `Content-Type` header in that case).

Comment: This is a bug introduced in the latest version of `requests`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the current `requests` master branch taken from GitHub. Don't, using the current development version can easily lead to problems as it is not yet release ready. The revision you are using contains a bug in the dictionary header merging code only present on Python 3; [this change](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/commit/276202f51ee9967969eafc1880c4785c80d63d3b) doesn't take into account that `dict.items()` is a live dictionary view on Python 3:

```
>>> requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', headers={'foo': None})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.4/requests/requests/api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.4/requests/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.4/requests/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.4/requests/requests/sessions.py", line 382, in prepare_request
    headers=merge_setting(request.headers, self.headers, dict_class=CaseInsensitiveDict),
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.4/requests/requests/sessions.py", line 66, in merge_setting
    for (k, v) in merged_setting.items():
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/_collections_abc.py", line 503, in __iter__
    for key in self._mapping:
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.4/requests/requests/structures.py", line 60, in <genexpr>
    return (casedkey for casedkey, mappedvalue in self._store.values())
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/2737) to fix the issue properly (now merged).

Your best bet is to stick with the latest release from PyPI (currently that is  [version 2.7.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/2.7.0) which is tried and tested.

If you can't use the PyPI version nor can you check out the current tip of the `master` branch, one work-around is to filter out `None` values from the dictionary before using the headers:

```
user_headers = {k: v for k, v in Config.get_headers().items() if v is not None}
```

Comment: https://github.com/dineshkumar-cse/SublimePluginHackerRank is the repo, it works fine with same python version, but later in local i 've refactored and it fails. what am i missing?